# How to get index of file before removing in angular-file-upload?

Tags: angularjs

I use [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API). I have event `ng-click="removeFile(item)"`.

Angular JS:

```
$scope.removeFile = function (item){
   console.log(item);
}
```

There is `index` param in object `item` by for me it is null. How I can get index of current file before removing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [in the in the demo](http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/image-preview/) they use `ng-click="item.remove()"` in images list and then `getIndexOfItem` [function is used internally](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/blob/master/angular-file-upload.js#L118) to obtain the index in the list of files. But in your wrapper `removeFile` you can have smth like this:

```
$scope.removeFile = function (item){
   item.remove();
  //index of the file in the list is - item.$index
    }
```